# Java SOAP Client Data Lost

Tags: java, ssl, soap, https

I have a Java client that sends data over HTTPS and the data is SOAP 1.1. I am not using any specific technology such as JAX-WS. The approach used is simple. When the SOAP response is sent, I get a 500 error from the error stream. It seems like when I run through Java the 500 error response is sent back and when running the same outside of Java which is Soap Sonar the response is perfect. It looks the some of the data is lost before it gets to the web service. How can this be debugged?

Below is the code:

```
public void sendSoap(String endpoint) {
     HttpsURLConnection httpsUrlConnection = null;
     URL url = new URL(endpoint);
     httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     httpsUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     httpsUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
     httpsUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
     SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
     sc.init(null, getTrustManager(), new SecureRandom());
     httpsUrlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSecureSocketFactory());
     httpsUrlConnection.connect();
     try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpsUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
        outputStreamWriter.write(buildData());
        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpsUrlConnection.getInputStream());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        InputStream inputStream = httpsUrlConnection.getErrorStream();
        inputStreamReader i = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader j = new BufferedReader(i);
        int read = j.read();
        while(read != -1) {
            String line = j.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
   }

public String buildData() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(new String("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"));
        stringBuilder.append(new String("<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:ns='http://somenamespace.com'>"));
        stringBuilder.append(new String("<soap:Body>"));
        stringBuilder.append(new String("<ns:service>"));
        stringBuilder.append(new String("<ns:message>message</ns:message>"));
        stringBuilder.append(new String("<ns:username>username</ns:username>"));
        stringBuilder.append(new String("<ns:password>password</ns:password>"));
        stringBuilder.append(new String("</ns:service>"));
        stringBuilder.append(new String("</soap:Body>"));
        stringBuilder.append(new String("</soap:Envelope>");
    }

 public TrustManager[] getTrustManager() {
   TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
       public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {

       }

       public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
           System.out.println("AuthType : " + " " + string);
           for(int i = 0; i < xcs.length; i++) {
               System.out.println("\t" + xcs[i].getIssuerX500Principal().getName());
               System.out.println("\t" + xcs[i].getIssuerDN().getName());
           }
       }

       public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
           return null;
       }
   }};
   return trustAllCerts;
 }
```

When copying the constructed String from buildData() and running through Soap Sonar it works.

EDIT:

This is what I receive from the error stream:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
       <title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
       <style type="text/css">
       <!--
            ody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
           ieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
           1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
           2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
           3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
           header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
           ackground-color:#555555;}
           content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
           content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
      ->
      </style>
  </head>
 <body>
   <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
  <div id="content">
  <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By itself a 500 response does not mean something has gone wrong in the message delivery. Whenever a server returns a SOAP Fault (which is perfectly legal message content) the response code will be 500.

Comment: Well the same data is sent through Soap Sonar and works correctly. The issue is with Java I assume. The data is flushed to the server endpoint but if you see above in the code the error stream contains data which returns a 500 Internal Server Error with the same SOAP envelope. If you don't think this is a message delivery problem, how can I debug this from the Java side?

Comment: I have added the edit above to show what I receive from the error stream through Java while executing the above code. From copying the generated XML from Java and run it through Soap Sonar it works.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? - I'm having the exact same issue at the moment..

Answer (score 0):

I think your immediate problem is in the server rather than the client. "Internal server error" suggests that the server is mishandling the request in some way. Do you have access to the server and/or its logs? Try to figure out what exactly it's doing when it receives your request.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out HttpURLConnection class getInputStream() method throws an IOException on HTTP status codes >= 400. So once an IOException is thrown there is no access to the getInputStream() method. The SOAP Fault itself can be accessed from the getErrorStream() method once a HTTP status code of >= 400 is returned. This could be achieved in the following way:

```
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConnection; 
InputStream is; 
if (httpConn.getResponseCode() < 400) { 
   is = httpConn.getInputStream(); 
} 
else { 
/* error from server */ 
   is = httpConn.getErrorStream(); 
}
```